# Flutter Persistence: how to jsonDecode a List<dynamic> to List<ClassType>?

Tags: json, flutter, asynchronous, serialization, persistence

I have a Todo-List app with Task class.
I want to serialize a Task List with jsonEncode and persist them onto a file in Docs dir.
after that, I want to be able to re-serialize the same list and convert them into my native List datatype (from List<String, dynamic> that I get from jsonDecode). Whats the best way to do it?

Currently, I tried:

```
void reSerializeTaskList() async {
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    File f = File('${directory.path}/new.txt');
    String fileContent = await f.readAsString();
    List<dynamic> jsonList = jsonDecode(fileContent).cast<Task>(); // does not  work
    print("JSONSTRING: ${jsonList.runtimeType}");
    print("$jsonList");
  }

I/flutter (29177): JSONSTRING: CastList<dynamic, Task>
E/flutter (29177): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Task' in type cast
```

my workaround is to iterate through all array elements and build a Task type out of the values with "fromJson" method inside my Task class:

```
  void reSerializeTaskList() async {
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    File f = File('${directory.path}/new.txt');
    String fileContent = await f.readAsString();
    List<dynamic> jsonList = jsonDecode(fileContent);

    List<Task> taskList = [];
    for (var t in jsonList) {
      print("T: $t and ${t.runtimeType}");
      Task task = new Task();
      taskList.add(task.fromJson(t));
    }
    print("JSONSTRING: ${jsonList.runtimeType}");
    print("$jsonList");

    print("$taskList");
    print("$taskList.runtimeType");
  }
```

my Task class:

```
import 'dart:io';

class Task {
  String name;
  bool isDone;

  Task({this.name, this.isDone = false});

  void toggleDone() {
    isDone = !isDone;
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    // TODO: implement toString
    return "${this.name} is done: $isDone";
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      "name": this.name,
      "isDone": this.isDone,
    };
  }

  Task fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    this.name = json['name'];
    this.isDone = json['isDone'];
    return this;
  }
}
```

But is there maybe another (better) approach? This looks quite patchy to me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to give you a little example, this is how I do it

```dart
final jsonResponse = json.decode(jsonString);
        final List<Customer> customers = jsonResponse.map<Customer>((jR) => Customer.fromJson(jR)).toList();
```

and fromJson in Customer class looks like this

```dart
  factory Customer.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Customer(
    id: json["id"] == null ? null : json["id"],
    changeDate: json["changeDate"] == null ? null : DateTime.parse(json["changeDate"]),
    name: json["name"] == null ? null : json["name"],
  );
```

Comment: thanks this works and looks better, but where is the difference in my method `  Task fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) ` and your method `factory Task.fromJson...` ? don't know much about that syntax yet..

Comment: factory avoids the creation of new instances. I think I have also done it like you have in the beginning, but since all examples used factory, I switched (so haven't experienced downsides personally). May main point was the first snippet with `.map`

Comment: when it answered your question, accepting the answer would be a nice gesture :-)